# How can I use Asp.Net Chart control in Asp.Net MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mschart

I know that there is a Chart control comes with the new Helpers library, but it doesn't have the same features as the Asp.Net Charting control. I have to represent a data where on the pie or the bar, I need to have a clickable link on the legend or the label.
I am using Asp.Net MVC 3 Razor and I couldn't tie the Asp.Net Chart control with this feature. I can show the chart but the links are not rendered. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can use ActionResult to render the chart. On the following link is a blog post of Daniel A Hill - [Rendering Microsoft .NET 4.0 Charts in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.danielahill.com/Blog/Rendering_Microsoft_Charting_MVC_Custom_ActionResult.aspx)

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting;

namespace Serviscope.Proviso.Web.Code
{
    public class ChartActionResult : ActionResult
    {
        private readonly Chart _chart;
        private readonly ChartImageFormat _imageFormat;

        public ChartActionResult(Chart chart, ChartImageFormat imageFormat = ChartImageFormat.Png)
        {
            if ( chart == null ) { throw new ArgumentNullException("chart"); }

            _chart = chart;
            _imageFormat = imageFormat;
        }

        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            var response = context.HttpContext.Response;

            response.Clear();
            response.Charset = String.Empty;
            response.ContentType = "image/" + _imageFormat;

            if ( _imageFormat == ChartImageFormat.Png )
            {
                // PNG can only write to a seek-able stream
                //  Thus we have to go through a memory stream, which permits seeking.
                using ( var mStream = new MemoryStream() )
                {
                    _chart.SaveImage(mStream, _imageFormat);
                    mStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    mStream.CopyTo(response.OutputStream);
                }
            }
            else
            { // If we don't have to provide a seek-able stream, write directly to
                //  where the data needs to go.
                _chart.SaveImage(response.OutputStream, _imageFormat);
            }

            _chart.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

and example:

```
public ActionResult MyChart()
{
  // Build Chart
  var chart = new Chart()
                  {
                    Height = 300,
                    Width = 400,
                    BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.TopBottom,
                    BackColor = Color.Gray,
                    BorderSkin = new BorderSkin() { SkinStyle = BorderSkinStyle.Emboss }
                  };

  // Add Chart Area and Set 3-D Settings
  chart.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea());
  chart.ChartAreas[0].Area3DStyle = new ChartArea3DStyle()
                                        {
                                          Enable3D = true,
                                          Perspective = 10,
                                          Inclination = 30,
                                          Rotation = 10
                                        };

  // Add Random values
  chart.Series.Add(GenerateRandomSeries(10, 10));
  chart.Series.Add(GenerateRandomSeries(10, 10));
  chart.Series.Add(GenerateRandomSeries(10, 10));

  // Return chart object, wrapped in our custom action result
  return new ChartActionResult(chart);
}

private static readonly Random RandomPointGenerator = new Random();
private static Series GenerateRandomSeries(int max, int count)
{
  var series = new Series();
  series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;

  for (int x = 0; x < count; x++)
  {
    series.Points.AddXY(x + 1, RandomPointGenerator.Next(max));
  }

  return series;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just create a standard webforms page inside your ASP.NET MVC application.
Scott Hanselman explains how to do that [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlugInHybridsASPNETWebFormsAndASPMVCAndASPNETDynamicDataSideBySide.aspx).